# Undefined local variable or method to_a in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This function...

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.open_subtotal
    sum{ |i| i.open_amount / (1.00 + i.tax_rate / 100.00) }
  end

end
```

...gives me an error in Rails 4.0.2:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling #sum with a block is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 4.1. If you want to perform sum calculation over the array of elements, use `to_a.sum(&block)`.

When I add `to_a` before `sum` I get an `undefined local variable or method to_a` error.

What is the correct way to write this?

Comment: what are you summing?

Comment: And why are you keeping money in floats? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: @MichalSzyndel: Actually all my money values are saved as `decimals` in the database. Will my code above mess that up?

Comment: Every time you write `0.4` it's a float in Ruby, so yes, it will mess up. If you have to multiply something by tax value use `BigDecimal.new` for instantiating tax rate.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel: Ah yes, will do. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
def self.open_subtotal
  all.to_a.sum { |i| i.open_amount / (1.00 + i.tax_rate / 100.00) }
end
```

But you can probably sum it in SQL (assuming `open_amount` and `tax_rate` are fields in your `invoices` table):

```
def self.open_subtotal
  sum("open_amount / (1 + tax_rate / 100)")
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is the way to do it nowadays...

```
select('sum(invoices.open_amount / (1.00 + invoices.tax_rate / 100.00) as open_subtotal')[0][:open_subtotal]
```

This does the calculations at the database level, appending as a new attribute `open_subtotal` which you then retrieve from the first instance of the select.

Taken from this blog.. http://stim371.github.io/blog/2014/02/12/deprecating-blocks-on-activerecord-count-and-sum/